# Difference between ために、せいで、おかげで when blaming someone

Tags: word-choice, words

I was reading and found the following sentence:

> あんたのために殺し屋の地位を失い闇の世界で迫害され身も心もズタボロになった。

Previous the same character used おかげで in a similar case:

> ま．．．おかげでたっぷりとあの時やられたお返しができるってワケだ。 あんたのおかげで殺し屋としてのあたしの信用がガタ落ち．．．ただブッ殺すだけじゃ気が済まないからねエ…

and:

> そして今度はあんたのせいでその娘【コ】が死ぬ！！

So I would like to know if there is any difference between ために、せいで、おかげで when used to blame someone.

Comment: おかげで is of course somewhat sarcastic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Used like in the examples you gave:
ために -- owing to; basically just a simple "because".
せいで -- used to pin fault / blame on something / someone.
おかげで -- like yuu-oniichan said, sarcastic, "thanks to"; lit. "due to the (unseen) (favourable) influence of"

And my spin on a translation using them:

あんたのために殺し屋の地位を失い闇の世界で迫害され身も心もズタボロになった。

> Owing to you I lost my station as hitman (woman really, I guess) and ended up getting the
>   literal and figurative shit beaten out of me in the scene (underground
>   / crime world).

ま．．．おかげでたっぷりとあの時やられたお返しができるってワケだ。 あんたのおかげで殺し屋としてのあたしの信用がガタ落ち．．．ただブッ殺すだけじゃ気が済まないからねエ…

> But, you know... thanks to that it means I get to get plenty of
>   payback for the time I took a beating. Thanks to you my rep as a killer
>   is in the gutter... I don't think just butchering you is going to be
>   enough for me...

そして今度はあんたのせいでその娘が死ぬ！！

> And now, because of what you brought on yourself, that one's gonna die!

Answer (score 2):

ために - For your sake, on your behalf
So, something was done for person A by person B or C, which person B is angry about over the outcome.

せいで - Because of you
Something done by person A or happened due to person A's influence or presence which person B is angry about.

おかげで - Thanks to you
Something done by person A or happened due to person A's influence or presence which person B is angry about. This has more of a sarcastic meaning.

Comment: But the ために in OP's sentence 「あんたのために殺し屋の地位を失い~~」 doesn't mean "for your sake, on your behalf" but "because of you", cos it can be rephrased あんたのせいで殺し屋の地位を失い~~

Comment: They all roughly mean "because of you." For me, that line has the nuance of "I lost my job (for you)," which you are rightly arguing that it can be switched to mean "I lost my job because of you," but they are slightly different. JP likes to be ambiguous, so interpreting with context is typically helpful.

Comment: 「They all roughly mean...」「but they are slightly different.」 <- Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean by the two "they", respectively? I'm Japanese, and I'm not very good at English, sorry